# Reverse engineering C object files

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, object-files

I'm practicing reverse engineering C object files. Suppose I have an object file of the C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
  char * input = argv[1];
  int result = strcmp(input, "text_to_compare");
  
  if (result == 0) {
      printf("%s\n", "text matches");
  }
  else {
      printf("%s\n", "text doeesn't match");
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

How would I go about finding "text_to_compare" from the object file given it was compiled with a -g flag and an x86-64 architecture?

Comment: This might be "too broad". But anyway, you would find the `main` function first, then the `call strcmp` in it then work backwards to see how the argument was set and that's where you will find your string. That's assuming you are actually looking for the "second argument to `strcmp`" and not just the string constant "text_to_compare" because that can simply be searched for.

Comment: As already said, search for how the compiler accesses the string literal; it will usualy be a label or section name, maybe plus some offset.  That will be where the string is stored.

Comment: Just read the disassembly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running `strings` on a binary file will all sequences of four or more printable characters in the file. For a simple file this might be sufficient, but for a larger file you can end up with a lot of false positives. For example, compiling your code with `gcc` and running `strings` on the resulting binary will return 295 results.

We can start by using the `objdump` command to disassemble the code in your sample file:

```
$ objdump --disassemble=main a.out

a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .init:

Disassembly of section .plt:

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000401136 <main>:
  401136:       55                      push   %rbp
  401137:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40113a:       48 83 ec 20             sub    $0x20,%rsp
  40113e:       89 7d ec                mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
  401141:       48 89 75 e0             mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
  401145:       48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
  401149:       48 8b 40 08             mov    0x8(%rax),%rax
  40114d:       48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
  401151:       48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  401155:       be 10 20 40 00          mov    $0x402010,%esi
  40115a:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  40115d:       e8 de fe ff ff          call   401040 <strcmp@plt>
  401162:       89 45 f4                mov    %eax,-0xc(%rbp)
  401165:       83 7d f4 00             cmpl   $0x0,-0xc(%rbp)
  401169:       75 0c                   jne    401177 <main+0x41>
  40116b:       bf 20 20 40 00          mov    $0x402020,%edi
  401170:       e8 bb fe ff ff          call   401030 <puts@plt>
  401175:       eb 0a                   jmp    401181 <main+0x4b>
  401177:       bf 2d 20 40 00          mov    $0x40202d,%edi
  40117c:       e8 af fe ff ff          call   401030 <puts@plt>
  401181:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  401186:       c9                      leave
  401187:       c3                      ret

Disassembly of section .fini:
```

Looking at the disassembly, we can see a call to `strcmp` at offset 40115d:

```
40115d:       e8 de fe ff ff          call   401040 <strcmp@plt>
```

If we look a couple of lines before that, we can see a instruction that is moving data from an address outside of this section (`0x402010`):

```
401155:       be 10 20 40 00          mov    $0x402010,%esi
```

If we look at the output of `objdump -h a.out`, we see that this address falls in the `.rodata` section (we're looking for sections for which the given address is in the block of memory starting at the address in the VMA column):

```
$ objdump -h a.out
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
[...]
 15 .rodata       00000041  0000000000402000  0000000000402000  00002000  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
[...]
```

We can extract the data in that section using the `objcopy` command:

```
$ objcopy -j .rodata -O binary a.out >(xxd -o 0x402000)
00402000: 0100 0200 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00402010: 7465 7874 5f74 6f5f 636f 6d70 6172 6500  text_to_compare.
00402020: 7465 7874 206d 6174 6368 6573 0074 6578  text matches.tex
00402030: 7420 646f 6565 736e 2774 206d 6174 6368  t doeesn't match
00402040: 00                                       .
```

And we can see that the string at address `0x402010` is `text_to_compare`.

Comment: @SaidHamed: Not that this answer is using `objcopy` on a linked executable, not a `.o` object file, which is why there are real addresses in the ELF section and program headers.  (Also because it's a non-PIE executable).  On a `.o`, you'd just get offsets relative to the start of a section.  (Unless you made an offset for `xxd`).

Comment: To disassemble a `.o`, normally you'd use `objdump -drwC -Mintel`.  The `-r` prints a relocation symbol-name as a comment next to instructions like `mov    $0,%esi` where the `0` is just a placeholder address to be filled in by the linker.

Comment: `strings -n 8` will only print runs of 8 or more printable characters, can be useful when the default is too noisy and you expect it to be non-tiny.